# Need help with avoiding lists in condition or pattern tests

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, pattern-matching, typechecking

How can we use a conditional or pattern test to make our function accept any symbols as input except for lists?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Can you include an example of what you'd like to avoid?

Comment: ohkaay! ill try again. How can we "Use a conditional or pattern test to make our function accept any symbols as input except for lists."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Except`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Except.html):

```
f[x : Except[_List]] := doSomethingTo[x]

expr /. x : Except[_List] :> doSomethingElseTo[x]
```

You can combine that with [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html) (infix operator `|`) to exclude several things:

```
g[x : Except[_List | _Rational]] := etc[x]
```

Edit: Consolidating answers from the comments too:

`ListQ[expr]` will return `True` if `expr` is a list (has head `List`) and `False` otherwise. `MatchQ[expr, _List]` and `Head[expr]===List` are equivalent ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: is there an easier approach for this ... i'm trying to use if condition here's my approach " checklogderivate [expr_] := 
  If[ expr = _List, "Invalid input form", D[expr , x]*(1/expr), 
   "Invalid input notation"];
"example: checklogderivate[{x^3 y^2, xy}]"

Comment: @Sunday: `expr = _List` should either be a `MatchQ[expr, _List]` or `Head[expr]===List`...

Comment: @Simon, @Sunday: there is also `ListQ[expr]` which returns `True` if `expr` is a list and `False` otherwise. TMTOWTDI =)

Comment: I decided to do it this way " If[ Length[expr] != 1,"invalid", do something specified, 0]"

Comment: @Sunday: Be careful with that, for example `Length[f[x]]` is `1` too.

Comment: And, e.g. `Length[3]` is `0`, so I don't see how that accomplished what you asked in the first place =)

Comment: @Michael  +1  Important observation about Length being unsuitable for determining whether one is dealing with a list.

Comment: How about this one...... checklogderivate [expr_] := 
  If[ Length[expr] != 1, "Invalid input form", D[expr , x]*(1/expr), 
   "Invalid input notation"];
checklogderivate[{3}]
checklogderivate[{x^3 y^2, xy}]

Comment: That works, but it wasn't what you asked about originally. You asked how to make sure a function argument isn't a list. `{3}`, for example, is still a list, and of length 1. `{3}` is really `List[3]`, the braces are syntactic sugar for the full expression. Everything is an expression in Mathematica. A function that takes one argument `x` could also be defined as `f[x_] := x+1`. A function that takes two arguments could be defined as `f[x_, y_] := x+y`. However, `f[x_]` would still accept a `List` as its one argument, because the pattern `_` will match anything.